# ReactJS issue on my test app

Tags: reactjs

So, I've been working through my first `ReactJS` app. Just a simple form where you type in a movie name and it fetches the data from `IMDB` and adds them as a module on the page. That's all working fine.

However each movie module also had a remove button which should remove that particular module and trigger a re-render. That's not working great as no matter which button you click it always removes the last movie module added rather than the one you're clicking on.

App: 
http://lukeharrison.net/react/

Github codebase:
https://github.com/WebDevLuke/React-Movies

I'm just wondering if anybody can spot the reasoning behind this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a hunch, but you should use a unique `key`, not just the index of the map function. This way React will understand that the movies are identified not by some iterating index, but an actual value, and that will probably solve your issue.

```
var movies = this.state.movies.map(function(movie, index){
  return (
    <Movie key={movie} useKey={index} removeMovieFunction={component.removeMovie} search={movie} toggleError={component.toggleError} />
  );
});
```

This is because React re-evaluates your properties, sees that nothing has changed, and just removes the last `<Movie />` from the list. Each Movie's `componentDidMount` function never runs more than once, and the state of Movie 1, Movie 2 and Movie 3 persists. So even if you supply `search={movie}` it doesn't do anything, because `this.props.search` is only used in `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Hey, this solved my issue. Thanks. I've not quite wrapped my head around why it works yet but it's given me something to look into.

Comment: It's actually quite simple if you can visualize it. On the initial render you create 3 movies, each with their own state: Movie 1/state 1, Movie 2/state 2, Movie 3/state 3. When you remove the first item, React sees that you still have a movie with key `0`, and thinks "Hey, that already has a state". So the new list will be Movie 2/state 1, Movie 3/state 2. Which is obviously wrong

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why it isn't rendering correctly as the dataset looks fine.

Looking at the code, I would change your remove function to this...

```
var index = this.state.movies.indexOf(movieToRemove);
console.log(this.state.movies);

if (index > -1) {
    this.state.movies.splice(index, 1);
}

console.log(this.state.movies);
this.setState(this.state.movies);
```

My assumption is that, the state isn't being updated correctly. Whenever updating state, you should always use setState (unless the convention changed and I wasn't aware).

Also, you shouldn't need to explicitly call forceUpdate. Once setState is called, React will automatically do what it needs to and rerender with the new state.

Answer (score 0):

State should be unidirectional (passed top down) from your top level component (known as a container). In this instance, you have state in your top level component for search strings and then you load individual movie data from within the "Movie" component itself via the IMDB API.

You should refactor your code to handle all state at the top level container and only pass the complete movie data to the dumb "Movie" component. all it should care about is rendering what you pass in it's props and not about getting it's own data.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm gonna def implement my next test React app in this way. I've found https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005#.l189qafjc which seems to be related.