# Reset the state of child from parent in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, frontend, reactjs

I'm designing a component called Subsection. What it does is basically show a row of tab buttons and when I click on one it shows the corresponding content right below itself.

So here's a snippet of how it gets setup.

```
<Subsection subsections={[{name:'name of sec1'},{name:'name of sec2'}, {name:'name of sec3'}]}>
  <div>this is sec 1</div>
  <div>this is sec 2</div>
  <div>this is sec 3</div>
</Subsection>
```

It shows a row of buttons like this:

```
+-------------------+---------------------+------------------+
|                   |                     |                  |
|   name of sec1    |    name of sec2     |   name of sec3   |
|                   |                     |                  |
+-------------------+---------------------+------------------+
```

It keeps track of a single state called index, and whenever I click on a button, it changes to the right index through `setState`

Then upon rendering, I select the right `this.props.child` by the index and show it. Here's an idea of it.

```
render() {
  ...
  this.props.children[this.state.index];
  ...
}
```

So far so good. Now here's the problem I ran into. I have a nested structure of subsections

```
<Subsection subsections={[{name:'1'},{name:'2'}]}>
  <Subsection subsections={[{name:'1.1'},{name:'1.2'}]}>...</Subsection>
  <Subsection subsections={[{name:'2.1'},{name:'2.2'}]}>...</Subsection>
</Subsection>
```

Which works well until I want to disable some button, say 2.1. When I first expand 1.1, and then click on 2, My 2.1 gets expanded automatically. Here's an illustration

Before:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|********************|                    |
|**********1*********|          2         |
|********************|                    |
+-----------------------------------------+
|********************|                    |
|*********1.1********|         1.2        |
|********************|                    |
+-----------------------------------------+
|                                         |
|                                         |
|                                         |
|              things in 1.1              |
|                                         |
|                                         |
|                                         |
+-----------------------------------------+
*for active Xfor disabled
```

After clicking 2:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|                    |********************|
|          1         |**********2*********|
|                    |********************|
+-----------------------------------------+
|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|                    |
|XXXXXXXXX2.1XXXXXXXX|         2.2        |
|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|                    |
+-----------------------------------------+
|                                         |
|                                         |
|                                         |
|              things in 2.1              |
|                                         |
|                                         |
|                                         |
+-----------------------------------------+
*for active Xfor disabled
```

Although 2.1 and 1.1 are managed by different Subsection component, 2.1 somehow 'inherits' the state of 1.1. One reason I could guess for this is  the 'diff'ing of React virtualDOM, which is unfortunately acting against my will in this case.

So here's the question: How am I able to prevent this inheritance upon clicking of button 2?

Comment: Mixed up component states are usually caused by bad `key`s in dynamically rendered components. If you can reproduce the issue in a minimal jsfiddle, I can take a look at it. Or see if the answer and following comments in this question makes you any wiser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36176436/reactjs-issue-on-my-test-app/36176959#36176959

Comment: Thanks for your tips! Now it's working fine now since I manually set the child's key. Any way to set the keys of child from parent?

Comment: It always depends. Ideally you want each child to have a unique ID, relative to the other children, in your data model. Then you just use that.